# JavaFX - tick mark label on NumberAxis

Tags: javafx

How do I get the string representation (as what is output on the graph) of the tick mark label on the NumberAxis? Which method can I use to read back what is being displayed on the NumberAxis.
For example, the x-Axis is displaying (1, 2, 3, ..., 10). When I use the tickMark.getLabel() of the tick mark label, I get (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ..., 10.0).  It is returning a double.  Does JavaFX use a default LabelFormatter method that converts the double to an integer before it displays on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

NumberAxis has a formatter field (inherited from VaueAxis) that converts the values to strings. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/chart/ValueAxis.html#setTickLabelFormatter-javafx.util.StringConverter-

You can overwrite it if it's not giving you the values you want.