# JavaFX NumberAxis With Text Tick Mark Values

Tags: javafx, charts

I am trying to create a JavaFX BarChart which replaces the numeric tick marks on the NumericAxis y-axis with a specific text value based on Likert scales.

For example: if I have a scale from 0 - 50, I would like 10 to be equivalent to "Disagree", 20 = "Somewhat disagree", 30 = "Neutral", 40 = "Somewhat agree" and 50 = "Agree".

Is this possible? I've tried using the setTickLabelFormatter method, suggested by: [JavaFX - tick mark label on NumberAxis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24834706/javafx-tick-mark-label-on-numberaxis). So far, I have worked out how to adapt the tick marks by adding various prefixes and suffixes, but not specific numerical values to text.

I would add code but don't think it's relevant to this question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you tried, but this is something you can start with.

```
myYAxis.setTickLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Number>()
    {
        @Override public Number fromString(String string)
        {
            // Reverse of toString()
        }
        @Override public String toString(Number object)
        {
            int value = object.intValue();
            if (value < 0 || value > 50)
                return "";
            else if (value <= 10)
                return "Disagree";
            else if (value <= 20)
                return "Somewhat disagree";
            // Etc
        }
    });
```

Comment: Yeah...I tried something similar but this does not work. This sets a general formatting rule for all the tick marks in the chart, not specific values. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: @Rufus So you want the values to be string values? If this is so, you can create a `BarChart<Foo, String>`, and instantiates it with `new BarChart(new FooAxis(), new CategoryAxis())`.